# Django query across multiple relationships

Tags: django, django-models

I have models following this pattern:

```
class House():
    name = *XYZ*

class Person():
    name = *XYZ*
    lives = ForeignKey(House)

class Item():
    name = *XYZ*
    owner = ForeignKey(Person)
```

How would I query items that are in a particular *House*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
Item.objects.filter(owner__lives__name="foo")
```